# How can I use reinforcement learning for product recommendation?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Based of user interactions in a e-commerce site, is it possible to design a product recommendation system using reinforcement learning? 
Are there any resources available online?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a good fit for reinforcement learning.

As discussed in [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-exactly-is-machine-learning-used-in-recommendation-engines) the "classic" way to recommend products is with supervised learning methods such as linear regression and classification.

There are several products that exist which offer this feature. For example, both [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/recommendations-using-machine-learning-on-compute-engine) and [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/mp/scenarios/bi/recommendation/) have some out-of-the-box recommendation services. You should probably check those out.

If you're interested in coding your own recommendation engine, [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/quick-guide-build-recommendation-engine-python/) is probably a good place to start.